# How can I use function with parameters in a stored procedure in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I need use `dbo.function(@nb int)` in a stored procedure in SQL Server, but I can't get the correct result (table is empty):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.procedure 
    (@var INT)  
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Qry VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @Qry = 'SELECT * FROM dbo.function(CONVERT(int,' + @var + '))'
    EXEC(@Qry)
END
...
```

Comment: Your procedure syntax is fine.  We can't answer this without knowing what the function is supposed to do, what your data looks like, what your expected results are, etc.

Comment: function is supposed to get a table with data, but i have only the rows name without data

Comment: Right.  That much is clear.  But how are we supposed to know when the function is supposed to return rows or not without seeing the code in the function?  Your question is basically "Why is this function returning 0 rows?".  The only response we can give you is "How are we supposed to know?"

Comment: when I call directly this function I have a good result (is a long code)

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using dynamic sql here in the first place? From what you have posted the dynamic sql is adding an unnecessary layer of complexity. Here is a much simpler approach to the problem.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.procedure (@var int)  
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM dbo.function(@var)
END
```

Comment: I use dynamic sql because I need set the row name by procedure's parametre :

Comment: huh?? That doesn't make any sense. You can't set a row name. And if you want the result name to be displayed a certain way you could do that in the front end instead of the database.